# Firebase Database auth variable does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The Doc says

```
Once a user authenticates, the auth variable in your Firebase Database Rules rules will be populated with the user's information. This information includes their unique identifier (uid) as well as linked account data, such as a Facebook id or an email address, and other info.
```

and i made and Auth in my app with google but when try reading the database it's return

```
Firebase Database error: Permission denied
```

where this is my rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "msgs":{
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.provider == 'google'",
    ".write":"auth != null && auth.provider == 'google'"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try auth !== null  it seems to want there to be two equal signs.

Comment: Interesting... Are you sure you're reading the msgs child node? Can you post th code you're using the get to that reference point?

Comment: yes because when i change the .read . write to true it works fine and i get the data in android side  

 DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.child("msgs");

Comment: Have you tried removing the provider type portion to see if your auth is null or not?

Comment: you mean like this ?  ".read": "auth !== null ",
    ".write":"auth !== null " ... yes same problem

Comment: Ok that looks like there is an issue authenticating then.

Comment: i'm sorry you soloution was correct , it was my fault that i forgot to enable Google Sign-in method in firebase console ..

Comment: There is no difference in Firebase Database security rules between `!=` and `!==`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank's for that info  the main problem was not enabling google sign in method .. for that auth variable was always null

Comment: Good to hear. But by marking this as the accepted answer, people may misunderstand that there is a difference between `!=` and `!==` (which isn't the case).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it sounds like, as you said it wasn't due to the amount of equals signs, but just a heads up. In the past for whatever reason it wouldn't auth for me unless I did !== as opposed to !=  I don't know why. They might have (hopefully) changed that in the new update.

Comment: As far as I know there has never been a difference between `==` and `===`. Given that the "old" way is still there, can you show what is giving problems on an "old" database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just stating something that came up for me a while back with one of the apps I was working on. 

When I used != it didn't work. I changed it to !== and it started to work. Since then I only ever used !==